# Displaying XML on web page from a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-view-controller

I am using ELMAH_Error. I am displaying the records in the admin section of the site so that i can view the errors. The last part of the record is an AllXml which outputs an XML type format. Everything displays okay when i am using the

```
<pre></pre>
```

tags. However there are some lines that are really long and i would like them to wrap. I have tried using

```
style="whitespace:pre-wrap"
```

but this seems to just bunch everything together and is very hard to read.

Is there some other tags i can put with this to help this look more appealing? 
There is not any XML tags in the record either. Below is my Razor page snippet for the xml part.

```
 <dd>
    <code>
       <pre lang="xml" style="max-height:400px;">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AllXml)
       </pre>
    </code>
 </dd>
```

Thanks for your help!